# Failed to initialized design editor after successful build

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello and I apologize for being such a rookie.

I've imported the UdaCity Project Sunshine code from GitHub, Android Studio says design editor is unavailable until next gradle sync. No problem, I've dealt with that before. Sync project from gradle files, but then I get a successful build, but the design editor still says failed to initialize.

I've tried to rebuild from the Build tab

I've cleared and invalidated caches and restarted.

I've watched four days of YouTube videos, but all the issues I'm finding are with an unsuccessful build, not a successful build.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Windows 10 Android Studio v 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I suggested to re-import the project and build the gradle and make sure you're not disconnected to the network. Check the configuration also. I faced the same issue and re-import my project.

Comment: I've tried re-importing it once each day. I've tried launching the project using the standard gradle and the Android gradle to no avail. What should I be looking for in configuration?